# Extract fields from json string converted from array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery SQL, I had an array which i turned into a json string using:

```
TO_JSON_STRING(array)
```

which gives me a field that looks like this:

```
[{"Key":"helpId","Value":"abcd1234"},{"Key":"userid","Value":"abc123"},{"Key":"accountid","Value":"ab12"}]
```

i'm trying to extract the keys using this:

```
 JSON_EXTRACT(json_string, '$.Key')
```

but it keeps returning null - any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '[{"Key":"helpId","Value":"abcd1234"},{"Key":"userid","Value":"abc123"},{"Key":"accountid","Value":"ab12"}]' json_string
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.Key') key, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.Value') value 
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string)) kv
```

with output

```
Row key         value    
1   helpId      abcd1234     
2   userid      abc123   
3   accountid   ab12
```

Hope you can easily apply above example to your specific use case